# Webhooks using Azure Functions

Tags: azure, webhooks

I am trying to implement webhooks for click funnels using Azure functions.

I've successfully created the function and added the route requested by click funnels, however when I try to test it in clickfunnels it isn't able to find the webhook - I get a `404 Not Found` error. When I test it in Azure, however, everything looks fine.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong? I am new to using webhooks so it may be something simple that is wrong.

Comment: Could you put here more details about your scenario? I just guess that you are forgetting something when you try to call your Azure Function from your WebHook.

Comment: Can you share the function.json (or a screenshot of the integrate tab)? The information here is a little limited.